Merging pointclouds while keeping previous merges intact [Open3D]
The goal is to create a pointcloud from a series of images I have, for the test part I generated images in Blender. For this post, I stitched all 12 of the images in a gif:

First, I load the images and set the camera params:
folder = 'Treasure_Chest/'
images = sorted([img for img in os.listdir(folder) if img.endswith(".png")])
image_paths = images
list_of_point_clouds = []
list_of_poses = []

# Camera parameters (Example values, should be obtained from calibration)
focal_length_mm = 50
sensor_width_mm = 36
image_width_px = 1920
image_height_px = 1080
f_x = (focal_length_mm * image_width_px) / sensor_width_mm
f_y = (focal_length_mm * image_height_px) / sensor_width_mm
c_x = image_width_px / 2
c_y = image_height_px / 2
K = np.array([[f_x, 0, c_x],
              [0, f_y, c_y],
              [0, 0, 1]])
global_pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
prev_pcd = None

Then, I calculate the keypoints and descriptors and store them:
# Create SIFT object
sift = cv2.SIFT_create(contrastThreshold=0.045)

# Create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2)

kd = []

print("Calculating keypoints and descriptors...")
for i in tqdm(range(len(image_paths))):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, image_paths[i]), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    keypoints1, descriptors1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    kd.append((keypoints1, descriptors1))

This is the core part of the code where I match the images. This is where I am facing the problem where, while creating a pointcloud the previously matched pointclouds keep disappearing. I will attach images for this problem later to explain it better. In this code, I stitch the pointclouds using ICP and append them to a variable. I do it for the inner loop as well as the outer loop.
def transform_points(points, R, t):
    # Apply the transformation to the points
    t = np.reshape(t, (1, 3))
    return (R @ points.T).T + t

def draw_registration_result(source, target, transformation):
    source_temp = copy.deepcopy(source)
    source_temp_2 = copy.deepcopy(source)
    target_temp = copy.deepcopy(target)
    source_temp.paint_uniform_color([1, 0.706, 0]) # Color: Orange
    target_temp.paint_uniform_color([0, 0.651, 0.929]) # Color: Blue
    source_temp_2.paint_uniform_color([0, 1, 0]) # Color: Green
    source_temp.transform(transformation.transformation)
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([source_temp, target_temp, source_temp_2])

for i in tqdm(range(len(image_paths))):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, image_paths[i]), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    keypoints1, descriptors1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    kd.append((keypoints1, descriptors1))

pcd_matches = []
# window_size = 500
print("\nMatching keypoints and descriptors...")

for i in tqdm(range(1, len(image_paths))):
    local_pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    inner_prev_pcd = None
    count = 0
    for j in range(0, i):
        keypoints1, descriptors1 = kd[i]
        keypoints2, descriptors2 = kd[j]

        # Match descriptors
        # matches = bf.match(descriptors1, descriptors2)
        matches = bf.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, k=2)

        # Sort them in the order of their distance
        # matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)
        matches = [m for m, n in matches if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance]

        if len(matches) < 76:
            continue

        # Extract the matched keypoints from both images
        points1 = np.float32([keypoints1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches])
        points2 = np.float32([keypoints2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches])

        # 'points1' and 'points2' are arrays of matched keypoints from two images
        # And 'K' is the camera matrix obtained from calibration
        E, mask = cv2.findEssentialMat(points1, points2, K, method=cv2.RANSAC, prob=0.999, threshold=1)
        _, R, t, mask = cv2.recoverPose(E, points1, points2, K)

        projMatr1 = np.hstack((K, np.zeros((3, 1))))
        projMatr2 = K @ np.hstack((R, t.reshape(3, 1)))

        # Triangulate points (homogeneous coordinates)
        points4D = cv2.triangulatePoints(projMatr1=projMatr1, projMatr2=projMatr2, projPoints1=points1.T,
                                         projPoints2=points2.T)
        points3D = points4D[:3] / points4D[3]
        points3D = points3D.T

        temp_pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
        temp_pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points3D)
        new_temp_points = transform_points(np.asarray(temp_pcd.points), R, t)
        temp_pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(new_temp_points)

        if inner_prev_pcd is None:
            local_pcd = temp_pcd
            inner_prev_pcd = temp_pcd
        else:
            transformation = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_icp(
                temp_pcd, inner_prev_pcd, max_correspondence_distance=1000,
                estimation_method=o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint(),
                criteria=o3d.pipelines.registration.ICPConvergenceCriteria(max_iteration=20000))
            temp_pcd = temp_pcd.transform(transformation.transformation)
            local_pcd = temp_pcd
            inner_prev_pcd = temp_pcd

    if prev_pcd is None:
        prev_pcd = local_pcd
    else:
        transformation = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_icp(
            local_pcd, prev_pcd, max_correspondence_distance=100,
            estimation_method=o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint(),
            criteria=o3d.pipelines.registration.ICPConvergenceCriteria(max_iteration=2000))
        local_pcd = local_pcd.transform(transformation.transformation)
        prev_pcd = local_pcd
    
    prev_pcd, _ = prev_pcd.remove_statistical_outlier(nb_neighbors=10, std_ratio=2.0)
    if i % 2 == 0 or i == len(image_paths) - 1:
        o3d.io.write_point_cloud(f'{ply_folder}/point_cloud_{i}.ply', prev_pcd)
    print(f"Number of points in the point cloud: {len(np.asarray(prev_pcd.points))}")

o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([prev_pcd])

This is the final output of the code:

Now, for the error, as seen in the code and the output gif, I save the pointclouds at even points and if I load the pointclouds for visualization, instead of seeing a complete box by the end, I am seeing parts of the box (output of the saved intermediate plys below). While visualizing intermediate outputs in the code, I found that as the pointcloud keeps being built, the previously added layers keep disappearing slowly. I am not sure what the error might be since I am not trying to remove the previously added layers and I can't seem to grasp why such a thing should happen. I'd appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

